# Conversion of curl multipart/form-data file upload command into python using requests library

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, curl, python-requests

I am trying to figure out how to get the following *curl* command into python using the **requests** library:

```
curl -u username:password -F package=@"/filesytem/path/to/file/we/want/to/upload.zip" http://url:port/crx/packmgr/service/.json/?cmd=upload
```

I have read both the source code and the documentation to the **requests** python library and tried a number of permutations but to no avail. The only thing that properly uploads a package into the site for the time being is this curl command but I need it programmed with the python **requests** library. Any ideas how to get this done ?

Comment: Check [this](https://curl.trillworks.com/)

Comment: @RJAdriaansen thanks I make heavy use of that tool but in this case the code that it generates for this curl command does not allow me to successfully upload files.

Comment: Also when you use `response = requests.post('http://url:port/crx/packmgr/service/.json/?cmd=upload', files={ 'package': open('/filesytem/path/to/file/we/want/to/upload.zip', 'rb') }, auth=('username', 'password'))`?

Comment: When I tried your suggestion I also got 
`{"success":false,"msg":"package file parameter missing"}` just like all the other attempts to use the requests library only when I use the curl command do I get `{"success":true,"msg":"Package uploaded","path":"..."}`

Comment: Ah, I see. Can you give this a try: `response = requests.post('http://url:port/crx/packmgr/service/.json/?cmd=upload', files={'package': ('upload.zip', open('/filesytem/path/to/file/we/want/to/upload.zip', 'rb'), 'application/octet-stream')}, auth=('username', 'password'))`

Comment: @RJAdriaansen that worked great. Thank you so much.